# Syntax error while running lex and yacc

Tags: c, compiler-construction, bison, yacc, lex

I am pretty new to lex and yacc. I was trying out a grammar that creates matrices and
performs some operations like adition,multiplication etc.

Here is the grammar I am using

```
 program:     block ENDS
 block:       stmt | block ENDS stmt
 stmt:        defn_stmt | init_stmt | print_stmt | oper_stmt
 defn_stmt:   DEF definitions
 definitions: MATID OPENSQ NUMBER COMMA NUMBER CLOSEQ ENDS | 
              definitions COMMA MATID OPENSQ NUMBER COMMA NUMBER CLOSEQ ENDS
 init_stmt:   INIT MATID [mat_contents]
 mat_contents: NUMBER | mat_contents COMMA mat_contents | mat_contents RANGE mat_contents
 print_stmt:  PRINT MATID
 oper_stmt:   MATID mat_operator inputs | MATID CMUL inputs
 mat_operator: ADD | MMUL
 inputs: MATID COMMA MATID
```

But for the following input am getting `syntax error` at second `DEF`.

```
 DEF A [2,3]; // defines a 2X3 Matrix A.
 DEF I [2,3]; // defines a 2X3 Matrix A.
 DEF BA[2,3],C[2,3], D[3,4], E[2,4];
```

ALso while running yacc its showing `conflicts: 4 shift/reduce`.

What causes the syntaxerror here? How can I correct it?

Comment: There's not really enough information there to tell - the definitions for all your terminals are missing. However, it does seem that your grammer doesn't include anything at all for dealing with the semicolons in your input...

Comment: @twalberg ENDS is for semicolon

Comment: In that case, your `definitions` expects to end with an `ENDS`, but then you also expect your `stmt`s to be separated by an `ENDS`... Maybe `DEF A [2,3];; DEF I [2,3];;` would avoid the syntax error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`definitions` must end with `ENDS` (<kbd>;</kbd>, apparently), which means that `defn_stmt` must end with <kbd>;</kbd>. However, a `stmt` must always be followed by a <kbd>;</kbd>. So the grammar insists that a definition be followed by *two* semicolons.

You should remove the `ENDS` from the `defn_stmt` productions. Also, you might want to factor out the two occurrences of `MATID OPENSQ NUMBER COMMA NUMBER CLOSEQ`; that's not the cause of your problems, though.

One obvious ambiguity (actually, two) is in the productions:

```
mat_contents: NUMBER
            | mat_contents COMMA mat_contents
            | mat_contents RANGE mat_contents
```

since it is (exponentially) ambiguous how to parse:

```
NUMBER COMMA NUMBER COMMA NUMBER RANGE NUMBER COMMA NUMBER
```

You could solve this with precedence declarations, or you could be more precise in your grammar.

Answer (score 1):

should be something like this, Not verified.

```
program:       block ; 
block:         stmt | block ; stmt 
stmt:          defn_stmt | init_stmt | print_stmt | oper_stmt 
defn_stmt:     DEF   definitions
definitions:   MATID  [NUMBER,NUMBER]  |  definitions,  MATID [NUMBER,NUMBER]
init_stmt:     INIT MATID [mat_contents] 
mat_contents:  NUMBER |  mat_contents ,  mat_contents |  mat_contents :  mat_contents 
print_stmt:    PRINT MATID 
oper_stmt:     MATID mat_operator inputs |  MATID CMUL  inputs
mat_operator:  ADD | MMUL 
inputs:        MATID, MATID
```

Comment: when posting an answer, you should explain what was wrong with their system, not just the code of the answer.  try to help them learn.